# An algebraic foliation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ which admits a non-algebraic complex limit cycle $L$ with $L\cap \mathbb{R}^2=\emptyset$

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, foliations, limit-cycles

Is there a  polynomial  vector field  on $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose  corresponding singular complex foliation of $\mathbb{C}^2 $ admits a complex limit cycle $L$ such that $L$ does not intersect the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2 $, **moreover $L$ is not an algebraic leaf**?

The following paper provide an example of this situation except the non-algebraic requirement.

In Question 1 of this note we pose the above question

https://maco.lu.ac.ir/article-1-86-en.html